# HTML form with GET method to PDF file ignores query string

Tags: html

I have this simple web form which has just a single button so the user can open a static PDF file when they click it.

Now that I've updated the PDF file, I updated the query string `timestamp` cache-busting parameter so they see a new version of the file.

```
<form action="Path/To/My/PDF Document.pdf?v=1234" target="_blank">
    <button>Get your PDF here!</button>
</form>
```

Well, the PDF opens up alright, but the querystring is automatically reduced to just the question mark.
What opens up is: `Path/To/My/PDF Document.pdf?`

This shows the original version and not the new one, and I'm wondering what is the matter with this process?

*I know method="GET" is not in my example, but it does the same with or without it.

Comment: May be server-routing related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a go:

```
<form 
 action="Path/To/My/PDF Document.pdf"
 method="GET">
   <input type="hidden" name="v" value="1234" />
    <button>Get your PDF here!</button>
</form>
```

Key points:

1. specify the method as GET
2. provide the query-string parameter as a hidden input, with the name set to the name of the query-string

The reason this works is because of how forms process input data.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/1tszbe5o/

Recommended reading for WHY this works: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data

TLDR: when you use the GET method, any form data provided with form inputs will be included in the query-string of the HTTP request resulting from the form action.

Why does it get stripped out in the first place? Because the form data was empty, hence the query-string was empty also ;)

Comment: Also - is there a reason you need to use a form here? This could be achieved more easily using an anchor tag, e.g. `<a href="my.pdf?v=1234">Download</a>`.

Comment: I just wanted to try it with a form and use the existing css for form buttons for downloading a pdf link. I can use anchors for this case with no problem too.

Comment: Oh yes, this totally worked and I'll probably just use simple <a> in the future but it's great to know these things! It still works even without specifying the method attribute too.